# Volume of intersecting oblique cylinders

Tags: calculus, geometry

The problem: Two oblique circular cylinders of equal height $h$ have a circle of radius $a$ as a common lower base and their upper bases are tangent to each other. Find the common volume.

I have a solution, below, but I arrived at it through an analogy, so I'm asking how others would solve this problem. This is problem 31 of Additional Problems of Chapter 7 of Simmons Calculus, and it is appearing around where many first semester courses in calculus might end. My initial approaches led to integrals a reader is not yet ready to solve in the book, so I kept looking til I found something.

The picture shows my approach. The sketch has sections of the intersecting regions shaded, they are like discs sliding past each other. Each overlapping area is symmetric, and each symmetric half is reminiscent of a rising or setting sun, which prompted the idea that a solution can be had by treating the volume similarly, since the rise of the sun at a constant rate over the horizon is equivalent to half the overlap section sliding up and down the cylinder. As the sun rises, the top surfaces first, then the rest of the disc according to its y-position. As we slide with constant speed from top to bottom of the cylinder, a point on the disc “rises” according to its y-position, $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$, until a semicircle has risen at the bottom. Once a sliver of disc rises, the constant continued rise forms a right triangle in section, with length proportional to when it rose, so length ~ $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$. So the triangle area is proportional to the square, area ~ $[\sqrt{a^2-x^2}]^2$, and the total of all these triangles is $\int_{-a}^{a} [\sqrt{a^2-x^2}]^2dx=\frac{4}{3}a^3$. Finally, the volume must be scaled to the height of the cylinder, so $V=\frac{4}{3}a^3 \frac{h}{a}=\frac{4}{3}a^2h$.

[image]

I am curious what other simple (or not simple) approaches solve this problem.

Comment: Isn't the formula for an oblique cone the same as a right one? I could be mistaken, though. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding to, but isn't the common area dependent on the angle at which the oblique cylinders are tilted away from each other?

Comment: The intersection is not an oblique cone (sorry, I know it's not a great drawing). The intersections sections turn from needle-like at top to an exact circle at bottom. But yes by Cavalieri's principle the volume of oblique and right cones (and cylinders) are the same.

Comment: I think your approach is completely rigorous: the intersection of the common volume with a plane parallel to both cylinder axes is a triangle, with base $2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ and height $h\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}$, where $x$ is the distance of the plane from the plane containing both cylinder axes. Integrating over these slices we get the volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an easier solution, but it is provided as a way to confirm that your solution is correct.

For a given height $h_0 \in [0, h]$ above the base, the cross-sectional area common to the two cylinders is given by the intersection of two circles of radius $a$ and distance between the centers $$d(h_0) = 2a \cdot \frac{h_0}{h},$$ since when $h_0 = 0$, the bases coincide, and when $h_0 = h$, the bases are tangent and thus their centers are separated by twice the radius, which is $2a$.

The area of this "lens" shape as a function of $d$ can be calculated via elementary trigonometry:  the angle $\theta$ between the line joining the two centers and a ray from one center to an intersection point on the boundary satisfies
$$\cos \theta = \frac{d}{2a},$$
thus the area is
$$A(d) = 4 \cdot \frac{1}{2} a^2 \theta - 2 \cdot \frac{d}{2} a \sin \theta = 2a^2 \cos^{-1} \frac{d}{2a} - \frac{d}{2} \sqrt{4a^2 - d^2}.$$
Written as a function of $h_0$, this is
$$A(h_0) = 2a^2 \left(\cos^{-1} \frac{h_0}{h} - \frac{h_0}{h} \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{h_0}{h}\right)^2}\right).$$
The total volume is therefore
$$\begin{align}
V &= \int_{h_0 = 0}^h A(h_0) \, dh_0 \\
&= 2a^2 h \int_{z=0}^1 \cos^{-1} z - z \sqrt{1-z^2} \, dz \\
&= 2a^2 h \left[z \cos^{-1} z - \sqrt{1-z^2} + \frac{1}{3} (1-z^2)^{3/2} \right]_{z=0}^1 \\
&= 2a^2 h \left(0 - 0 + 0 - 0 + 1 - \frac{1}{3}\right) \\
&= \frac{4}{3} a^2 h.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much - this is the route I started down, but the relevant trig integrals aren't for another few chapters.